# Find coordinate a certain distance and heading away from another coordinate

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geometry

I am using the *Google Maps Geometry Library* two calculate both the distance and heading between two points:

```
...computeDistanceBetween(coord1, coord2) // = 10 m.
...computeHeading(coord1, coord2) // = 25
```

From this I want to find a point, based on another known coordinate, which is also 10 m. away, in the same direction (heading):

```
...computeDistanceBetween(coord3, unknown) // = 10 m.
...computeHeading(coord3, unknown) // = 25
```

How would one go about calculating unknown in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `computeOffset`.  From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical):

> computeOffset(from:LatLng, distance:number, heading:number, radius?:number)
>
> Return Value:  LatLng
>
> Returns the LatLng resulting from moving a distance from an origin in the specified heading (expressed in degrees clockwise from north).

```
var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(coord1, coord2);
var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(coord1, coord2);
var newPt = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(coord1, distance/2, heading);
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var coord1 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.399228, -122.208676); // SouthWest corner
  var coord2 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.484548, -122.075124); // NorthEast corner
  var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(coord1, coord2);
  var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(coord1, coord2);
  var newPt = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(coord1, distance / 2, heading);
  console.log(newPt.toUrlValue(6) + ", distance=" + distance.toFixed(2) + ", heading=" + heading);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: newPt,
    map: map
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly the method I nedded! Thanks!